# Brand new computer build, Windows 10 black screen before installation

Tags: windows-10

I just a built a brand new computer.

- CPU: Intel Celeron G3900
- Motherboard: Asus z270-P
- Memory: 4Gb
- Graphics Card(s): MSI Radeon RX 570- Gaming

I am using Mac OS and used a software called `unetbootin` to burn the Windows 10 disk image on the USB memory stick, I don't own another windows PC to burn with Rufus.

I plug the USB memory stick and start the computer I get the Windows logo and the loading dots, after that the screen turns completely black.

I'm using a TV and HDMI cable.

The fast boot is disabled in BIOS, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have 1 or more graphic card(s)? Is it black as in "switched off" or black as in "switched on, but black screen", and how long have you waited for something to happen? Have you tried different usb-ports for your pendrive? Have you tried flashing the ISO to another pendrive? Have you changed anything in the BIOS (fast-boot shouldn't be a problem)?

Comment: Hey @flolilolilo I have only one graphic card connected to this motherboard.  The screen looks like it's on but black. I tried 3 usb pendrives (1 usb3 and 2 usb2) none work, all of them just show the windows logo and that's it. I bought 1 usb stick just an hour ago. Some other bios settings where changed but it was compared to another brand new computer where windows work ( the other computer is 2500 km away I can't test my usb in it)

Comment: @flolilolilo I waited the black screen about 10 minutes and nothing changes.

Comment: Some things I'd try (*these are just wild guessings*): -BIOS: Try different settings for EHCI-handover, USB legacy support and USB boot initialisation. also, see if UEFI and CSM are enabled. -ISO: Maybe try another program to "burn" it. Personally, I never got unetbootin to work properly (but I have the luxury of using windows for that. AFAIK, Boot Camp Assistant *might* work. -try different usb-ports (both USB 3.1 and USB 2). -if all of that doesn't help and noone else has any suggestions, try to flash & run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) on your pendrive to see if it's an HW-issue.